# Rationalsing and simplifying surds question grade 10

Tags: fractions, rationalising-denominator

I am a student and I am having difficulty answering this rationalising and simplifying question: I don't know what to do with the 2 at the bottom as a fraction.

[image: Curds question]

Thank you and help is appreciated

Comment: ambiguous: it could be $(a/\sqrt{40})/2$ with value $a/(2\sqrt{40})$. You should place parentheses...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\frac{a}{\frac{\sqrt{40}}{2}} = \frac{2a}{\sqrt{40}} = \frac{2a}{\sqrt{5*2^3}} = \frac{2a}{2\sqrt{10}} = \frac{a}{\sqrt{10}} = \frac{\sqrt{10}a}{10}$$

Comment: Thank you for helping me understand this question☺